# Use _TIME_BITS=64 to solve the y2038 problem

Tags: arm, glibc, buildroot

I added the macro of _TIME_BITS=64 to Buildroot, and the system can set the time after 2038 after compilation, but if it exceeds 2038, my timestamp is -1, how to solve it

## date -s "2038-11-23 00:00:00"

Tue Nov 23 00:00:00 UTC 2038

## date +%s

-1

Comment: Please provide more info about your setup. What Buildroot version and config are you using exactly? What kernel version? Notice that we have a BR2_TIME_BITS_64 option since Buildroot 2023.11

Comment: Buildroot version:2022.11 kernel version:5.10.21

Comment: Dear Mr. Peter Korsgaard, I found that in order to upgrade the kernel header version of the compiler to above 5.1, I recompiled a cross tool through the crosstool-ng tool, which caused the timestamp to always be -1. I used the cross tool chain from the arm official website. I downloaded the latest version 13.2 and successfully solved this problem, but the cross tool kernel header version on the official website is 4.20. I am really honored to receive your reply.